# What did Apocalypse mean by this line?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In the climax of [X-Men Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse),

> Apocalypse's last words were: "**All has been revealed**" before being obliterated by Jean/Phoenix.

What did he mean by this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has direct reference to the sequel, which will have the Dark Phoenix Saga, as confirmed by Simon Kinberg [here](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Rebooting-Dark-Phoenix-Saga-Here-What-Simon-Kinberg-Says-106727.html).

Also during an interview, the director Bryan Singer [exclaimed](http://www.fandango.com/movie-news/the-next-x-men-movie-may-take-place-in-outer-space-750859) the possibilities to use the **"big alien, interstellar tenant within the X-Men universe that has not been explored."**

Now from what some of us might be knowing from the DPS is that it features Jean Grey (as Phoenix) going head to head against the Shi'Ar - alien empire, who can very well destroy the Earth as we know it. This possibility of expanding the existing X-Men universe with the Dark Phoenix Saga might (and it is a speculation) usher in the Shi'ar, the character rights of which Fox [owns](http://comicbook.com/2015/05/29/guardians-of-the-galaxy-director-clarifies-who-owns-kang-and-the/).

So, Apocalypse's dying words are (based on Circumstantial Evidences) a forewarning of the Shi'Ar.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

There was no need to destroy the world cause he now knows the Phoenix would do it

Comment: Hi! Your answer is probably correct, but we usually want answers to have a bit more detail. Could you expand upon your reasoning?

Comment: Would be great if you could add more details :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a more powerful being than him and I'd put money on it that the shi-ar have been on earth before and met Apocalypse  and then thousands of years later possibly hidden the power of the Phoenix within Jean Grey

Answer (score 1):

Jean saw the end of the world in her dreams ... but who's end of the world was it? She said it felt so real ... but it never came true. so apocalypse is referencing the dark Phoenix saga as she will now struggle to control that power and almost destroy the earth. She will go head to head with the shi'ar and almost destroy the earth in the process. Or apocalypse was just meaning all has been revealed as in magneto and storm betrayed him.

Answer (score 0):

I believe apocalypse also had that vision. And believed it was to be him thats caused all that destruction. So when Jean shows him the power of the Phoenix. He understands it's will be her that will destroy.

Comment: Could you add some more details?